# Read in file path then open file in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an annoying issue that I cannot figure out. I am trying to pass a file path programmatically to a function but it tells me that my file path does not exist. When I pass the same file path to the function manually it runs without an issue. any help on this would be appreciated.

```py
import pandas

#function1:
#reads in CSV_FilePath from pandas DataFrame
#adds file paths to filecollection list.

#for example:
filecollection = ["\\server\path\to\file.csv"]

for filename in filecollection:
     function2(filename)

#function2 (CSV_filePath):
data = pd.read_csv(CSV_FilePath)
#do some stuff to the data DataFrame
#Save the data
```

When I call `function2("\\server\path\to\file.csv")` everything runs fine.

When I call `function1` which collects the file paths and then passes them to `function2` I would get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'"\\server\path\to\file.csv"' does not exist: b'"\\server\path\to\file.csv"'
```

The file does as exist. I thought this maybe was an issue with the `\\server` prefix and tried it on a mapped drive K:\ and that didn't seem to be the issue. I have tried prefixing "r" in `function2 (data = pd.read_csv('r'+CSV_FilePath))` and that didnt seem to help either.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Be sure to include actual `def` lines for your functions. And include the code for `function1()`.

Comment: try using `"//server/path/to/file.csv"` if that doesn't work for you try escaping the \\ like so `"\\\\server\\path\\to\\file.csv"`

Comment: I think you are confusing the `r'/path/to/file` syntax with prepending an `'r'` character to a string. These are **not** the same thing. Read about so-called "raw string literals" to learn more.

Comment: The key here is correctly building a string that has the exact path to the file you want to open. This is always tricky.

Comment: try `pathlib` so you can deal with posix path instead of string, if you import module you can do something `Path.joinpath(filename)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit sily example but works.

```
import pathlib
import os

path = "H:\\Directory of files\\"

for filename in os.listdir(path):

print(filename)

if pathlib.Path(path+filename).exists():

    print ("File exist")

    # Call function2 here with the file path and file name

else:

    print ("File does not exist")
```

Comment: try using `.joinpath` to avoid string concatenation here